# Make datatables use ajax HTTP GETs per row instead of standard <a href> link

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am using [datatables](http://datatables.net/) jquery plugin together with asp.net

I have the following code that renders a link

```
        "columns": [
        {
            "data": "Id", "render": function (data) {
                return '<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-color-primary" href="@(Url.Action(Model.ActionUrl))?id=' + data + '"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-@(Model.ActionIcon)"></i></a>';
            }
        },
            { "data": "Id" },
            { "data": "FirstName" },
            { "data": "Surname" },
            { "data": "Company" }
        ],
```

in a datatable

`@Actionurl` is a url to the /Controller/Method with the rows Id

`@ActionIcon` is either `Edit` or `Detail`

This code works when you click on the edit icon but it renders a whole new page. 
I want to rather make an ajax call so I can return a modal dialog from my server.

Question:
How do I change the above datatables code to instead make an ajax call to the server instead of currently it is just an standard `<a href` link which refreshes the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fail to see the real problem. Just replace the anchor tag with a `<span>` element triggering an ajax call `onclick`?

```
funtion ajax(data) {
   $.ajax({
      url: '@(Url.Action(Model.ActionUrl))?id=' + data,
      success: function(response) {
         //do whatever here
      }
   })
}
```

...

```
render: function (data) {
  return '<span class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-color-primary" '+
         'onclick="ajax('+data+');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-@(Model.ActionIcon)"></i></span>';
}
```